# Why does SSL fail in Starman

Tags: perl, ssl, starman

My setup works perfectly until I enable SSL.

This

```
starman -p 3001 app.psgi
```

works fine, but this:

```
starman --enable-ssl --ssl-cert a.crt --ssl-key a.key -p 3001 app.psgi
```

does not - generating this error:

```
Could not finalize SSL connection with client handle (SSL accept attempt failed error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request)
```

on every request.

Running on perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 on AWS's Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Ports seem to be forwarded ok:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https redir ports 3001
2    REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https redir ports 3001
3    REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt redir ports 3001
4    REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 3001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could not finalize SSL connection with client handle (SSL accept attempt failed error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request)

This indicates that the client has send a HTTP request instead of the expected HTTPS request. Please check all URL's used by the client - they should all be `https://` and not `http://` since you setup your server to be accessible by HTTPS only.

Comment: Gotcha! Yes - it's true! However I now found out that going to https times out. Any idea? Should I re-ask the question?

Comment: Turns out you need to enable https on AWS's firewall rules on the console

Answer (score 0):

I has such issue and resolved it by installing
**python-certbot-apache**
from debian apt repo

But now i have another issue:

SSL_cert_file /etc/letsencrypt/live/..*domain_here*../cert.pem can't be used: Permission denied at /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 2375.

chown of dir doesn't help.